# Getting Map resolution in google maps

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3, openlayers

How can i get the map resolution using google maps  api that is in nature similar to the

value that is got from openLayers map.GetResolution

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the open layers resolution correctly I think it should be as simple as this:

```
156543.0339 * Math.cos(1.57078734) / Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Baz1nga's answer is close but wrong. The value you're trying to calculate is meters per pixel at **equator**. So the answer should be

```
156543.0339 * Math.cos(0) / Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
```

Its cos(0) because latitude is 0 at equator. cos(1.57078734) is always 0. Using the same logic, if you replace the value in cos() with the latitude in radians, you would get the meters per pixel value at that latitude.
Note that his is based on the assumption that the earth's radius is 6378137.

[Source](https://groups.google.com/g/google-maps-js-api-v3/c/hDRO4oHVSeM/m/osOYQYXg2oUJ)